# Accessing an input value with HTML and PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, post, textbox

I am very new to php and need some help please!

I am using a text box to display a value from a table which I would like then be able to be edited and used for an update statement.

This text box currently gets populated based on what the $studentId is and this works fine.

```
$conn = connection();

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE studentId=$studentId";

    foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
    ?>
      <form>
        Student Name: <input name="name" type="text" method="post" value="<?php echo( htmlspecialchars( $row['name'] ) ); ?>" />
        <br>
        <input name="submitStudentUpdate" type="submit" value="Update" /> 
    </form>
    <?php
    }
```

connection(); is being provided from another page.

It's this line I need the value of

```
Student Name: <input name="name" type="text" method="post" value="<?php echo( htmlspecialchars( $row['name'] ) ); ?>" />
```

I would like to retrieve the value from this form and post to another page to be used in an update statement but how do I get at it?

I thought it may be:

```
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {

    echo $_POST['name'];

}
```

So currently, text box gets populated with

[Bob]

And I would like to be able to change it to, e.g.

[Bobby]

hit the submit button and retrieve this value.

I am using PDO.

Hope this makes sense and any help much appreciated. Thankyou.

Comment: why does the input have 'method="post"'? FORM tags have that attribute, not inputs.

Comment: I realized that was my error. Thanks @JAL :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't define the method in your form so it defaults to get

So you should be able to get your value via `$_GET['name']`

I hope I'm understanding you correctly.

```
<?PHP
    if(isset($_GET['name'])) {

       $sql = "UPDATE students SET name = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name'])."' WHERE studentID = '".(int)$_GET['studentId']."' LIMIT 1";

       // or with pdo prepared statements (more secure)
       $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE students SET name = ? WHERE studentID = ? LIMIT 1");
       $stmt->execute(array($_GET['name'], $_GET['studentId']));

    }        
$conn = connection();

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE studentId=$studentId";

        foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
        ?>
          <form>
            Student Name: <input name="name" type="text" method="post" value="<?php echo( htmlspecialchars( $row['name'] ) ); ?>" />
            <br>
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $studentId; ?>">
            <input name="submitStudentUpdate" type="submit" value="Update" /> 
        </form>
        <?php
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: I know it's just an example for simplicity's sake, but since this is a basic question, I'm guessing the programmer is not adept at PHP, so I think it'd be better if we encouraged escaping. `"UPDATE students SET name = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name'])."' WHERE studentID = '".(int) $_GET['studentId']."' LIMIT 1";`

Comment: @M Miller actually, the asker says he/she is using PDO. You're recommending use of the mysql_* library apparently, which is the wrong one to use, additionally, since it's deprecated.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't know PDO offhand, and I would've used `mysqli_`, but that was even more complex since I'd have to instantiate an object.... The query should really be prepared. My bad, should've looked up PDO. Heck, even `addslashes` would at least be better than what was above.

Comment: added pdo example to answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$conn = connection();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE studentId=$studentId";

if( isset($_GET['studentId']) )
{
   "UPDATE FROM students SET name = '".$_POST['name']."' WHERE studentId=".$_POST['studentId'];
}

foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
?>
  <form action="?studentId=<?php echo $row['studentId']; ?>" method="post">
    Student Name: <input name="name" type="text" method="post" value="<?php echo( htmlspecialchars( $row['name'] ) ); ?>" />
    <br>
    <input name="submitStudentUpdate" type="submit" value="Update" /> 
</form>
<?php
}
```